# Error on setting d attribute of an arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

my browser is throwing me two errors when I'm working on a pie chart with d3.js library.

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M1.4695276245868527e-14,-240A240,240 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z"
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNA240,240 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z"
```

Here is part of my code:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

d3.json('...', function (error, json) {

    var g = chart.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(json))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc) // <-- problem
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            console.log(d.data.count);
            return color(d.data.count);
        });
});
```

I would really appreciate your help, because I found d3.js to be a great help. Have a nice day.

Comment: You'll need to show us your complete code and example data. It looks like it may be a problem with the definition of `pie`. Check that you're accessing the correct attribute in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LarsKotthoff comment I found error.

I had to change:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) {
            return d;
        });
```

to:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) {
            return d.count;
        });
```

Thanks and have a nice day!